# IOS traffic-export equivalent for Junos

Tags: cisco, ios, juniper, network-traffic, junos

In IOS the traffic-export command allows you to take incoming packets and send them, unaltered, to a specific interface. Is there an equivalent way to do this in Junos? I've got a J-series 2350 here. Initially I was going to look at the port mapping feature, but it isn't supported on this hardware. It has a packet capture feature, but the packets are written to disk instead of being sent out another interface.

I want to be able to capture all packets, even those that may be dropped at layer 3+ by firewall rules or whatever else, and send them out another interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the Cisco SPAN feature.

Juniper calls this port mirroring, and it isn't supported on the J 2350.

[Juniper KB](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB15901)

Comment: What's on the other end of the ethernet cable, can you mirror the port on the other side?